# How to use category theory diagrams with polyary functions?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

So, there's a lot of buzz about categories all around the Haskell ecosystem. But I feel one piece is missing from the common sense I have so far absorbed by osmosis. *(I did read the first few pages of Mac Lane's famous introduction as well, but I don't believe I have enough mathematical maturity to carry the wisdom from this text to actual programming I have at hand.)* I will now follow with a real world example involving a binary function that I have trouble depicting in categorical terms.

So, I have this function chain that allows me to `S -> A`, where `A` is a type synonym for a function, akin to `a -> b`. Now, I want to depict a process that does `S -> a -> b`, but I end up with an arrow pointing to another arrow rather than an object. How do I deal with such predicament?

I did overhear someone talking about a thing called *n-category* but I don't know if I should even try to understand what it is and how it's useful.

Though I believe my abstraction is accurate, the actual functions are `parsePath >>> either error id >>> toAxis :: String -> Text.XML.Cursor.Axis` from `selectors` and `Axis = Text.XML.Cursor.Cursor -> [Text.XML.Cursor.Cursor]` from `xml-conduit`.

Comment: You'd probably be interested in looking at the idea of a [closed category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_category) (and possibly the more specific [closed monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_monoidal_category) as well). Also, this might belong more over on https://cs.stackexchange.com (or maybe even https://math.stackexchange.com). Finally, I'm not sure how your last sentence relates to the rest of the question.

Comment: You might be interested in [Category Theory for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/). Note that you should interpret the title as meaning "Category theory explained in terms programmers will understand", not (as I originally did) "Bits of category theory that will be immediately usable in your code" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use tuple projections to depict this situation, as follows:
[image: categorical depiction of the case at hand, in symbols]

-- Or, in actual Haskell terms:
[image: categorical depiction of the case at hand, in actual terms]

This diagram features backwards `fst` & `snd` arrows in place of a binary function that constructs the tuple from its constituents, and that I can in no way depict directly. The caveat is that, while in this diagram `Cursor` has only one incoming arrow, I should remember that in actual code some real arrows `X -> Axis` & `Y -> Cursor` should go to both of the projections of the tuple, not just the symbolic projecting functions. The flow will then be uniformly left to right.

Pragmatically speaking, I traded an *arrow with two sources* (that constructs a tuple and isn't a morphism) for *two reversed arrows* (the tuple's projections that are legal morphisms in all regards).

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches to model binary functions as morphism in category theory (n-ary functions are dealt with similarly -- no new machinery is needed). One is to consider the uncurried version:

```
(A * B) -> C
```

where we take the product of the types `A` and `B` as a starting object. For that we need the category to contain such a products. (In Haskell, products are written `(A, B)`. Well, technically in Haskell this is not exactly the product as in categories, but let's ignore that.)

Another is to consider the result type `(B -> C)` as an object in the category. Usually, this is called an exponential object, written as `C^B`. Assuming our category has such objects, we can write

```
A -> C^B
```

These two representations of binary functions are isomorphic: using `curry` and `uncurry` we can transform each one into the other.

Indeed, when there is such a (natural) isomorphism, we get a so called *cartesian closed category*, which is the simplest form of category which can describe a simply typed lambda calculus -- the core of every typed functional language.

This isomorphism is often cited as an adjunction between two functors

```
(- * B) -| (- ^ B)
```

Comment: As I see it, then, the `Axis` in question is that exponential object: `[Cursor] ^ Cursor`. Now, should I connect `Cursor` & `[Cursor]` with a very long, arrow-shaped exponential object? Or rather forfeit the idea of drawing a cartesian closed category with a pen & paper?

Comment: @Kindaro It depends on what you want to achieve. In general, these constructions can be helpful in rewriting a program in pointfree style, but sometimes this results is code which is much more complex than its pointful variant. E.g. writing `uncurry id` is not the best way to describe a function taking `(f,x)` and returning `f x` -- even if this is a basic result in cartesian closed categories. Personally, I like using `(&&&),(***)` from the `Arrow` module when they can shorten boring code, still I usually am quite conservative on abusing pointfree style.

Comment: @Kindaro You should provide more information about what you're trying to do. I strongly suspect that trying to look at it from a category theory perspective will not help you out here in the first place (unless the actual objective is just to learn about category theory), but we need a bit more info.

Comment: @DavidYoung Starting from the suggestions that a category may be depicted as a graph, and that Haskell types form a category (even if more complicated than **Set**), I wanted to test the assumption that a fragment of a Haskell program may be depicted as a graph. Now, for the case at hand I am at loss searching for a depiction. I should now think awhile more and perhaps assume not all categories are graph-depictable (specifically, not those of which a hom-set is itself an object) and that an otherwise correct Haskell program fragment will oft happen to belong to such a category.

Comment: @DavidYoung Please take my word for the fact that my layman-level interest in category theory is founded on the more practical interest in Haskell. I had easily found practical benefit applying some elementary category-theoretical concepts to my code (for example, identifying unary functions within a module with iso, monic & epi morphisms and depicting their relationships helps me understand what collection of functions I should export to expose a smallest complete interface), but on polyary functions I'm so lost I can't even depict the code in terms of morphisms anymore!